# Link between Trend data and prediction

Tags: regression, time-series, classification, trend

Say I have a data sequence of 200 people playing an online game and the game has 5 levels. In each level, each person faces the same number of enemies which he must kill. Moreover, we have IQ values of each person as well. Now, I am looking for a learning algorithm to predict IQ based on trends in killing enemies in each level. The data is something look like (number in parenthesis is number of enemies in each level)

```
ID  Level-1(10)  Level-2(12)  Level-3(9)  Level-4(5)  Level-5(10)   IQ
#1      8             9           6           3            4       100
#2      4             8           6           4           10       120
```

For example, the first person starts well at beginning (kills 80%) but decays when going to higher levels (%75, %67, %60, %40) while the second applicant becomes better when levels go up (%40, %66, %66, %80, %100). How to map this trend to the IQ values so that if a new person plays the game we can estimate his IQ without performing IQ test?

Comment: how much data do you have ? ie for how many people do you have the IQ and the kill values ?

Comment: Say 200 people.

Answer (score 0):

With these types of problems you should try to fit a few models from data then evaluate how they perform .Linear regression predicts the target variable (IQ) using linear combinations of the predictor variables (different level scores )and seems a reasonable place to start  .

You can  explore linear regression in python at (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html ) then improve with other non linear models if need be . Once you have figured out the model you can predict IQ scores for other players from their level scores .

Youll find that https://www.dataquest.io/blog/machine-learning-python/  is a good post.

edit : you could safely normalise by dividing with max kill count per level for example for the first level it would be 10.